# SVG animation with CSS and :hover

Tags: css, svg, transform

I'm trying to animate svg path when mouse is over the container dom element(a), which is bigger than svg element itself(for bigger contact area). I can't rotate whole container, because svg element will contain some more paths, which should be static. Now green arrow does not accept the initial position when mouse leaves, that I would like to see happen.

https://jsbin.com/juqene/18/edit?html,css,output

HTML:

```
<div id="outer">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="56" height="56" viewBox="0 0 56 56">
        <path id="arrow" fill="none" stroke="#21B469" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M26.637 55.68L.583 28.346 25.333.32"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#arrow {
     transform: none;
}

#outer:hover #arrow {
   transform: rotate(10deg);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this

```
#arrow {
  transform: none
}
```

to this

```
#arrow {
  transform: rotate(0);
}
```

```css
#inner {
  width: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#arrow {
  transform: rotate(0);
}
#outer:hover #arrow {
  transform: rotate(10deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="56" height="56" viewBox="0 0 56 56">
    <path id="arrow" fill="none" stroke="#21B469" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M26.637 55.68L.583 28.346 25.333.32" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: You are faster than light). Works perfectly.